# Elements in 2d list repeated, while changing one value?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

The following is python code, I initialize a 2-d list using operator *, and set the diagonal elements with other value. But get unexpected output.

```
table = [([False]*5)]*5
for i in range(5):
   table[i][i] = 1
```

The expected output is

```
[[True, False, False, False, False],
 [False, True, False, False, False],
 [False, False, True, False, False],
 [False, False, False, True, False],
 [False, False, False, False, True]]
```

But I got

```
[[True, True, True, True, True], 
 [True, True, True, True, True], 
 [True, True, True, True, True], 
 [True, True, True, True, True], 
 [True, True, True, True, True]]
```

May the elements in the list refers one, I guess. How could I get the expected output without using numpy or other packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be explicit in your `table` construction via nested `for` loops, otherwise the pointers in your list will all point to a *single* list. This is why, in your code, assigning one elements affects all elements.

```
table = [[False for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]

for i in range(5):
    table[i][i] = True

# [[True, False, False, False, False],
#  [False, True, False, False, False],
#  [False, False, True, False, False],
#  [False, False, False, True, False],
#  [False, False, False, False, True]]
```

---

A better idea, if you are happy to use a 3rd party library, is to use a `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

table = np.eye(5).astype(bool)

# array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
#        [False,  True, False, False, False],
#        [False, False,  True, False, False],
#        [False, False, False,  True, False],
#        [False, False, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```